# Why embedded Derby database doesn't accept binary operators with date?

Tags: java, jdbc, derby

I am using embedded derby database in a Java program.
My database query is:

```
"SELECT ID, NAME, MOBILE_NUMBER FROM CLIENTS2 WHERE CONTRACT_DATE <= ? AND BUILDING_ID = "+buildingId
```

And I am setting the date via prepared statement:

```
try {
            PreparedStatement pStmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
            pStmt.setDate(1, endSqlDate);
            try (ResultSet rs = pStmt.executeQuery()) {
                while(rs.next()){
                    FinancialInfoModule financialInfoObj = new FinancialInfoModule();

                    financialInfoObj.setClientId(rs.getInt("ID"));
                    financialInfoObj.setMobileNumber(rs.getInt("MOBILE_NUMBER"));
                    financialInfoObj.setClientName(rs.getString("NAME"));
                    getClientFinancialInfo(financialInfoObj, startSqlDate,
                            endSqlDate);

                    if(financialInfoObj.isMeetingTheNeed()){
                        financialInfoList.add(financialInfoObj);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ReportsUtility.class.getName())
                    .log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

But every time I get this error :

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "WHERE" at
>   line 1, column 61.    at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.handleException(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleException(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.ConnectionChild.handleException(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement.(Unknown
>   Source)

Does anyone have an idea what is happening?

Comment: Your problem doesn't seem related to using `<=`, otherwise I would have expected the error there and not about `where`. On a separate note, you obviously know how prepared statements work. Why are you using parameters to set the date, but concatenating `buildingId`? Use a parameter for that as well.

Comment: Print out `query` for debugging and look what is at column 61 in the string

Comment: Are you **absolutely certain** that this is the SQL statement you are running? In the SQL statement you include in your question, the `WHERE` is at column 46.

Comment: i think it was just an error masking, i solved it but i don't know how ! 
thanks @Mark Rotteveel for your note i will take care of it in my code.